# Showing loading image in window.open for an external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a loading image icon for the links to external sites when the pop-up is opened through a window.open() function.

I thought of an approach, where show the loading image in a 'div' and get the content of the external site in an Ajax call, then re write the content. Since these are external domains, $.get("external-link") won't work (although might work with some workarounds i don't links).

Is there another approach to tackle this, appreciate pointers. Thanks

Comment: Is your question about loading images or cross-domain ajax calls?

Comment: Its about showing a loading image icon when opening a pop-up window for external sites

Comment: Do you want to show the loading icon inside of the new window, or on the calling page?

Comment: inside the new window

Comment: Well, what you describe is how it's often done.

Comment: okay, so is there a cleaner way yo get the content of a an external site through Ajax call, thank you

Comment: added a live example to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can load the content into an iframe, showing the loading image when the link is clicked, and hiding it when the iframe has loaded:

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" class="ilink">click me</a>
<br/>
<div id="dummyloader" style="display: none; width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: gray"><h2>loading</h2></div>
<iframe src="" id="myframe" style="display: none;" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.ilink').click(function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            $('#dummyloader').show();
            $('#myframe').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));

        })

        $('#myframe').load(function(){
            $('#dummyloader').hide();
            $(this).show();
        })
    })
</script>
```

live jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/L01d5t5a/

Comment: thanks for your answer, and your solution works, but wondering if iframes are supported in all browser and if its a good choice for enterprise application

Comment: @Greg yes I frames are supported in all popular browsers. It's about the only simple solution to your problem - ajax won't work for external sites unless you build a server side proxy to tunnel through